# Scrollable list of buttons within SliderDrawer

Tags: android, slider, scrollable

No luck after a few days of researching this one.  Should be simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

There is an activity page, which has a SliderDrawer.  SlidingDrawer icon sits at the bottom, on click or swipe slides open drawer correctly with list of buttons.  That all works fine.  The problem I'm having is that to accomodate different screensizes and orientations, and the likely addition of additional buttons, I need the contents of that SlidingDrawer to be scrollable.  Layout is below. I have tried wrapping the LinearLayout that holds the buttons in a ScrollView without success.

Suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/frontpagetitlewrapper"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="blah"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/mid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="and"
        android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top"
    android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="blather"
        android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mid"
        android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
   </LinearLayout>
   <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content" 
        android:id="@+id/slide" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@id/handle" 
        android:src="@drawable/opendrawer">
    </ImageView>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@id/content" 
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button android:text="a" android:id="@+id/btnA" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"></Button>
            <Button android:text="b" android:id="@+id/btnB"   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"></Button>
            <Button android:text="c" android:id="@+id/btnC"   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"></Button>
            <Button android:text="d" android:id="@+id/btnD" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"></Button>
            <Button android:text="e" android:id="@+id/btnE" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"></Button>
            <Button android:text="f" android:id="@+id/btnF" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </SlidingDrawer>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<SlidingDrawer android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="250dip">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
        android:background="@drawable/closearrow"></Button>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center|top" android:padding="10dip"
        android:background="#C0C0C0" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Content"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you've tagged the nested LinearLayout with instruction

```
android:id="@id/content"
```

so that's the component the SlidingDrawer is using for the content.
Try tagging the ScrollView instead.